# Aggregate records by time

Tags: mysql

I have a query to perform aggregate records, by time, but I have some errors.

My situation: I store stock market data in MySQL db vers 5.6 one record per minute from 0900 up to 1730, that's 511 records per day

[image]

I need to aggregate these data for different time frame, let's suppose 5 minute, so that

**volume5min** -> sum volume 0900 : 0904

**open5min** -> open value for 0900 record (first open value in range)

**close5min** -> close value for 0904 record (last close value in range)

**high5min** -> highest value in 0900 to 0904 range

**low5min** -> lowest value in 0900 to 0904 range

and so on.

I have a query to accomplish this, but I get errors in open and close aggregated values

```
SELECT 
    floor(cast(time as SIGNED) / 5) as timeInterval,
    date,
    time,
    MAX(high) AS high,
    MIN(low) as low,
    SUM(volume) as volume,
    (select 
            open
        from
            atlantia a2
        where
            a1.time = a2.time
        order by time
        limit 1) as open,
    (select 
            close
        from
            atlantia a2
        where
            a1.time = a2.time
        order by time desc
        limit 1) as close
FROM
    atlantia a1
GROUP BY date , timeInterval
```

This is what I get executing the query

[image]

open and close are not aggregated correctly while the other columns seems good.

What's more, changing the aggregate time frame I get incorrect time, such as the 60 min example below

[image]

Starting from 0900 I should have 1000, 1100 and so on while now I also have 1020, 1140 etc.

Columns type are:

date : CHAR
time : CHAR
all the rest are DOUBLE but Volume that is INTEGER.

How to modify this query to get values properly aggregated?

**Edit:** in order to verify your last query, I have manually checked any single hours and these are the correct values I should get

[image]

Your query returns differences on close values, all the rest it's ok

[image]

Close value should be the last record for the time frame, i.e. for time between 0900 and 0959 close is the 0959 value in close column.

**Edit 2:** It seems I have found where the trick was, now with this query it all works fine

```
 SELECT 
 Sub1.timeInterval, 
 a1.date,
 MIN(a1.time),
 MAX(a1.high) AS high,
 MIN(a1.low) as low,
 SUM(a1.volume) as volume,
 a2.open as open,
 a3.close as close
 FROM atlantia a1
 INNER JOIN
 (
 SELECT floor( (cast( SUBSTRING(time,1,2) AS SIGNED ) * 60 + cast( SUBSTRING(time,3,2)   AS SIGNED )) /60 ) AS timeInterval, MIN(time) AS minTime, MAX(time) AS maxtime
 FROM atlantia
 GROUP BY timeInterval
 ) Sub1
 ON floor( (cast( SUBSTRING(a1.time,1,2) AS SIGNED ) * 60 + cast( SUBSTRING(a1.time,3,2)    AS SIGNED )) /60 ) = Sub1.timeInterval
 INNER JOIN atlantia a2 ON a2.time = Sub1.minTime AND a1.date = a2.date
 INNER JOIN atlantia a3 ON a3.time = Sub1.maxtime AND a1.date = a3.date
 GROUP BY a1.date , timeInterval
```

What if I want to aggregate in different time frame, i.e 5 minutes? Do I just change both /60 with /5?

Thanks

Comment: My last query works fine for 60 min, and also for 5, 10 min and so on. There are aggregation problems for odd time frame divisions, such as 7 or 11 minutes. Any suggestion about how to solve really appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot a couple of issues.

You are storing the time in a character field and when that is cast as a signed 10:20 o'clock is treated as 1020 rather than as 10 * 60 minutes + 20 minutes. Hence when divided by 60 10:00 is 16 while 10:20 is 17, hence in your code they are 2 different time intervals.

The other issue is that you have returned time as a field without it being specified in the GROUP BY clause. The value of time it will return is from an undetermined row (normally the first but not always). Probably easiest for this to specify MIN(time).

```
SELECT 
    floor( (cast( SUBSTRING(time,1,2) AS SIGNED ) * 60 + cast( SUBSTRING(time,3,2) AS SIGNED )) /60 ) AS timeInterval, 
    date,
    MIN(time),
    MAX(high) AS high,
    MIN(low) as low,
    SUM(volume) as volume,
    (select 
            open
        from
            atlantia a2
        where
            a1.time = a2.time
        order by time
        limit 1) as open,
    (select 
            close
        from
            atlantia a2
        where
            a1.time = a2.time
        order by time desc
        limit 1) as close
FROM
    atlantia a1
GROUP BY date , timeInterval
```

Might be possible to clean up the sql to remove the sub queries.

EDIT

Had a play and this might do it, but not sure of the efficiency and without the tables I can't test it:-

```
SELECT 
    Sub1.timeInterval, 
    a1.date,
    MIN(a1.time),
    MAX(a1.high) AS high,
    MIN(a1.low) as low,
    SUM(a1.volume) as volume,
    MIN(a2.open) as open,
    MIN(a3.close) as close
FROM atlantia a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT floor( (cast( SUBSTRING(time,1,2) AS SIGNED ) * 60 + cast( SUBSTRING(time,3,2) AS SIGNED )) /60 ) AS timeInterval, MIN(time) AS minTime, MAX(time) AS maxtime
    FROM atlantia
    GROUP BY timeInterval
) Sub1
ON floor( (cast( SUBSTRING(a1.time,1,2) AS SIGNED ) * 60 + cast( SUBSTRING(a1.time,3,2) AS SIGNED )) /60 ) = Sub1.timeInterval
INNER JOIN atlantia a2 ON a2.time = Sub1.minTime AND a1.date = a2.date
INNER JOIN atlantia a3 ON a3.time = Sub1.minTime AND a1.date = a3.date
GROUP BY a1.date , timeInterval
```

Comment: @Kickstart...thanks, your code fix the time interval issue, but still have incorrect values for open and close.

Comment: Think the issue there is that you are getting the open and close value for any rows which match the time at the start of any time period, but you are not checking for the date as well. I will have a play at a better solution.

Comment: @Albertoacepsut - had a quick play

Comment: Get this error by executing the query Error code 1052, SQL state 23000: Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous
Line 1, column 1

Comment: Column 'time' in field list is ambiguous It seems the same error for the other columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46437/discussion-between-alberto-acepsut-and-kickstart)

Comment: Try now. About to go for lunch though.